# Decide if the following function is integrable on $[0,2]$

Tags: real-analysis

hello I am beginner in this field so can you help me?

the problem is to decide if the following function is integrable on $[0,2]$ and calculate integral when I can
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ x-2, & 1 \leq x \leq 2  \end{cases}   $$

so if I suppose that the function is integrable on $[0,2]$ then I'll have

$$\int_{0}^{2} f(x) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) + \int_{1}^{2} f(x) $$but when $x = 1$  I have two functions $ f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = x- 2$ and I haven't met things like that :))  so what should I do can you help me?

Comment: By definition, a function can only take one value at a time, so $f$ as it's expressed there is not even a function. However, I'm sure it's a mistake and one of the inequalities is strict. On the other hand, integration is a "kind" operation and it lets one carry one with weird functions. In this case, there's only one problem at the point $x=1$, which can be ignored because it's a measure-zero set, so it doesn't affect the final result.

Comment: Are you sure the source didn't have $0 \leq x < 1$ or $1 < x \leq 2$ in the definition of $f$? As written it's not a function ($f(1) \neq f(1)$?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you don't want an actual 'proof' that $f$ is integrable. But in general, yes piece-wise continuous functions are integrable. More specifically, if you have two integrable functions $g,h:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ and you define the function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ to be $$f(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)&\text{ if }x\in[a,c]\\h(x) &\text{ if }x\in(c,d]\end{cases}$$ then $f$ is integrable and $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{c}g(x)dx+\int_{c}^{b}h(x)dx$$
([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350326/deriving-that-piecewise-continuous-functions-are-integrable))

In your case, the piece-wise functions are integrable and your idea to split the integrals in that manner is the best way to evaluate the integral in question.

As one person has already pointed out, you have a typo in the definition of your function $f$, making it not a function since it maps $1$ to $1$ and $-1$. This can be easily fixed by changing the condition to be $f(x)=x$ for $x\in[0,1)$.